# Room database observer

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-room

In Room database, I want to add some observer where the notifications are like: delete, insert, update.

I did kind of achieve that by creating an interface, and the adapter implement it. So each time one of the Database transactions is over, a matching operation is performed on the adapter.

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, maybe rxjava has some way of doing it? Or maybe the DiffUtil in RecyclerView?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use Rxjava for it.

With the help of `android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1` in your dependency you can directly observe changes in your database.

**Dao.kt**

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM table")
    abstract fun getAllData(): Flowable<List<TableData>>
```

**Repository**

```
fun getDataFromDb():Flowable<List<TableData>>= database.dao().getAllData()
```

**ViewModel**

```
repository.getDataFromDb()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeBy{
                        //Todo here you will receive the data whenever there is any change in database
                     }
```

Also point to note

Room only knows that the table has been modified but doesn’t know why and what has changed. Therefore, after the re-query, the result of the query is emitted by the LiveData or Flowable. Since Room doesn’t hold any data in memory and can’t assume that objects have equals(), it can’t tell whether this is the same data or not.You need to make sure that your DAO filters emissions and only reacts to distinct objects.

If the observable query is implemented using Flowables, use Flowable#distinctUntilChanged

```
   Flowable<TableData> = repository.getDataFromDb()
                          .distinctUntilChanged{previous,next-> //here you can check for difference }
```

you can follow this link for more detail

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1

Comment: Yes, this sends a call when anything happens and doesn't specify what changed

Comment: Updated the answer please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You should return LiveData objects from your Dao methods to observe CRUD operations.

LiveData will get updated when any CRUD operation is performed on your repo.

Then you can get updated data from your repo and reflect the changes in the adapter.

Comment: Yes. But both LiveData and Flowable/Observable return the whole list of data if anything changes.

Comment: Correct. To further find the difference between the original data and new data, you should use DIffUtil.